# Can I get the current user from Active Directory LDAP using a VBA ADO Connection?

Tags: vba, active-directory, ldap, ado

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the current logged in Active Directory username from VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574777/how-do-i-get-the-current-logged-in-active-directory-username-from-vba)

Is there any way to retrieve the user ID of the currently logged in user from Active Directory services using LDAP over an ADODB connection in VBA?

I have only seen examples of how to query additional information about a user by specifying the user name and password. In those examples the user name is generally retrieved using `Environ("username")`, but some of the users of my application log onto the network using a VPN, and their Windows user name may not be the same as the user name used to log onto the network via the VPN.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043436/how-do-i-get-the-current-user-identity-for-a-vpn-user-in-a-windows-forms-app

Comment: Whoops. Already asked this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574777/how-do-i-get-the-current-logged-in-active-directory-username-from-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**: Active Directory by itself doesn't know if someone is logged in. There's no way you can do something like:

```
ActiveDirectory.getIsThisUserLoggedIn("username");
```

Active Directory only acts as a mechanism for user metadata, security, and authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nalandial. I did try going the VBA route, but haven't received any answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532343/how-to-query-cisco-vpn-state-and-username-from-vba and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574777/how-do-i-get-the-current-logged-in-active-directory-username-from-vba

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know: "Active Directory by itself doesn't know if someone is logged in." So the answer to this question is "No."